# proper permissions under HTTP root with Apache2 + FastCGI + Suexec

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, php, fastcgi

I currently have a setup which runs Apache2 + FastCGI PHP + Suexec.

As an example, I'm using `/mnt/data/www/vhosts/inflex.co.uk/htdocs` as a DocRoot for one of my virtual hosts.

I have a script `/mnt/data/www/php5-cgi/inflex.co.uk/php5-cgi` which contains:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

The account the scripts should run under is `duncan`, this file is owned by duncan and also in the group duncan. It has `-rwxr-x---` permissions.

`.../www/vhosts/inflex.co.uk` and `../inflex.co.uk/htdocs` is owned by duncan and in the group duncan.

If I remove all access for others, such as `chmod 750`, I get an error regarding permissions when trying to access the website, if I allow read/write for others, 755 say, it works.

I'm assuming this is an issue with `www-data` (apache2 user) accessing the directory, but I thought the point of Suexec was that all of this was ran under a seperate user, or does `www-data` require read (maybe write?) on the folder and then executes PHP php file as the user?

Comment: Ok, had another look with a fresh pair of eyes, turns out you need to have o+x so that the directories can be tranversed by others.

Comment: But it seems that files still need to be readable by others (or www-data)